# previous/next record button php/mysql woes

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql

My question deals with my next/previous buttons. I can get my update/delete buttons to work, but I'm so ready to tear out my hair when dealing with the next/previous buttons. Any help would be spectacular! Here's my code. Also, I'm pretty new to PHP so if this is bad coding, please let me know and point me in the right direction so I can fix my mistakes. Thanks!!!

```
session_start();

include "connectionfile.php";

if (isset($_POST['fname']) &&
isset($_POST['lname']) &&
isset($_POST['email']) &&
isset($_POST['login']) &&
isset($_POST['password']) &&
isset($_POST['super']) &&
isset($_POST['foldername']))
{
$id = get_post('id');
$fname = get_post('fname');
$lname = get_post('lname');
$email = get_post('email');
$login = get_post('login');
$password = hash('sha256', get_post('password'));
$super = get_post('super');
$foldername = get_post('foldername');

if ($_POST['submit']==0){

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Logins` WHERE ID < '".$id."'  ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
   $id = $row['ID'];
   $fname = $row['fname'];
   $lname = $row['lname'];
   $email = $row['email'];
   $login = $row['login'];
   $password = $row['password'];
   $super = $row['super'];
   $foldername = $row['foldername'];

}
}else if ($_POST['submit']==1){
$query = "UPDATE Logins SET fname = '$fname', lname='$lname', email='$email".'@carouselclinical.com'."', login='$login', password='$password', super='$super', foldername='$foldername'";
$query .= "WHERE ID = '$id';";
if (!mysql_query($query, $connect))
echo "INSERT failed: $query<br />" .
mysql_error() . "<br /><br />";

}else if($_POST['submit']==2){

$delete_query = "DELETE FROM Logins WHERE ID = '".$id."';";
mysql_query($delete_query);
$rc = mysql_affected_rows();
echo "Rows Affected " . $rc;

}


if ($_POST['submit']==3){

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Logins` WHERE ID= '". $id ."' ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1;");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
   $id = $row['ID'];
   $fname = $row['fname'];
   $lname = $row['lname'];
   $email = $row['email'];
   $login = $row['login'];
   $password = $row['password'];
   $super = $row['super'];
   $foldername = $row['foldername'];

}

}
}

mysql_close($connect);

function get_post($var)
{
return mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
}
?>

<form action="" method="post"><pre>
id <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="id" value="<?php echo "$id"; ?>" />
First Name <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo "$fname"; ?>" />
Last Name <input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo "$lname"; ?>" />
Email <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo "$email"; ?>" /> There's no need to put @carouselclinical.com.
Login <input type="text" name="login" value="<?php echo "$login"; ?>"/>
Password <input type="text" name="password" value="<?php echo "$password"; ?>"/>
Super? <input type="text" name="super" value="<?php echo "$super"; ?>" />
foldername <input type="text" name="foldername" value="<?php echo "$foldername"; ?>" />
<button name="submit" value="0">Previous</button>
<button name="submit" value="1">UPDATE</button>
<button name="submit" value="2">Delete</button>
<button name="submit" value="3">Next</button>
</pre>
<a href="super.php">Home</a> <br />
<a href="logout.php">Log out</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Your question isn't all that clear, but it seems that you might need to pass the `id`s for next and previous so in mysql you can actually access the right data set.

Comment: Not sure exactly what problem you're having, but one thing that might throw you off is that you are using `==` instead of `===` for checking `$_POST['submit']`. Any string value, when compared to 0 using `==` will evaluate to **true**. Not sure if this is causing a problem for you, but you should definitely be aware of it.

Comment: Also, you should avoid using `mysql_*` functions, and use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead. And you also shouldn't use `mysql_fetch_array()` if you just need the string keys. Use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead. Well, don't use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` either. Use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: I'm sorry for being unclear.  I can't get my previous/next buttons to work.  I don't think I fully understand what needs to happen.  Right now, I have a page that is supposed to show different information about the user, but all I get is a bunch of blank text boxes.  How do I pass the information from either the `$_POST['submit']==0` or the `$_POST['submit']==3` section to the form at the bottom?

Comment: You need to explain what you mean "Previous and next buttons to work" - what do you WANT them to do?  Is this a form of pagination?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: It looks like you're doing that correctly by setting variables and then echoing them in the `value` attribute of the text boxes. So if you are still getting blank text boxes, you should try and debug why those are not getting set. Try adding some random `echo` statements in key areas of your code. Put an `echo "Line ". __LINE__ ."\n";` in each of your if-else blocks to see which one (if any) is executing. Try doing an `echo "fname = {$fname}"` at a couple different places in your code. Try `var_dump($_POST);` to see what that contains.

Comment: It looks like all of your initial vars are set via `$_POST`. When you load the page for the first time are you posting all those fields? If not, then this would cause all your text boxes to be empty, and when you click on the buttons nothing will happen as the read-only `id` field will be empty as well.

Comment: @cale_b it's to select the previous/next record from my database

Comment: @Sean I guess I'm not posting those fields correctly.  How would I post to those txtboxes when the page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an `else` right above `mysql_close($connect);`. My guess is that on the initial page load you are not posting any values, so no action is taken. This will create a default `ID` if none is defined in your top `if`.

```
else{
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Logins` ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1;");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  $id = $row['ID'];
  $fname = $row['fname'];
  $lname = $row['lname'];
  $email = $row['email'];
  $login = $row['login'];
  $password = $row['password'];
  $super = $row['super'];
  $foldername = $row['foldername'];
}
```

Also, on your `if ($_POST['submit']==3)`, you need to change the `=` to `>` in your `$query` so you can get the next record. Currently you would be selecting the same ID, not the next higher.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Logins` WHERE ID > '". $id ."' ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1;");
```

Finally, when doing Previous/Next you also need to take into consideration how you will deal with `Previous` when you are on the first `ID`, and `Next` when you are on the last `id`, as you will return an empty result set from `MySQL`.

Comment: Holy crap!  @Sean That was exactly the problem.  I wasn't populating the textboxes on the initial page load.  Also thanks for spotting the query error!